# Counting number of edge pixels in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, pixel, canny-operator

I want to count the number of edge pixels in a given image. I tried it by counting pixels of white color of the image we get by using Canny operator on the image.

```
I = rgb2gray(imread('replay1.jpg'));
bw = edge(I,'canny');
numberOfBins = 256;
[r, cl, x] = size(bw);
[pixelCount, grayLevels] = imhist(bw);
c = sum(pixelCount(pixelCount==255));
disp(c*100/(r*cl));
```

## Questions:

**1.** But this somehow gives the same answer for all images, which suggests I am doing it wrong. How should I find number of edge pixels of an image in matlab?

**2.** Also can I use canny operator on YCbCr format of an image? I tried doing that but it gives me errors.

[image]

Comment: @herohuyongtao sorry..edited the code, but this always shows me 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PART 1**

Use this - `count_edge_pixels = nnz(bw)` This is a very efficient way to calculate true (1) values that are edge pixels in this case and thus, would give you count of edge/white pixels as calculated from [edge](http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/edge.html).

**PART 2**

You can use `edge` on each of Y, Cb, Cr separately or just use Y for edge detection on the luminance part. Use [this](http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/rgb2ycbcr.html) to get YCbCr from RGB images.

Let's suppose you would like to get edge information on the luminance map of the image, do something like this -

```
YCBCR = rgb2ycbcr(imread('replay1.jpg'));
luminance_map = YCBCR(:,:,1); 
bw = edge(luminance_map,'canny');
```

Hope this makes sense and works for you!

Comment: Can you please explain the second point. I have not worked much on images, and using `Y for edge detection...`, I didn't get anything from it, however `nnz()` seems to be giving right results for grayscale images.

Comment: You don't need to do all those histogram calculations. Just get `bw` from `edge` and use `nnz` as stated in code.

Comment: Yeah,I understood that..I directly used nnz.. Thanks for the explanation. That made it clear.

Answer (score 1):

**`pixelCount(2)`** will give you the number of edge pixels here. As @Divakar mentioned, `nnz(bw)` will also work as expected.

```
I = rgb2gray(imread('test.jpg'));
bw = edge(I,'canny');
numberOfBins = 256;
[r, cl, x] = size(bw);
[pixelCount, grayLevels] = imhist(bw);
count = pixelCount(2);  // <- here, or use "count = nnz(bw)"
```

---

To detect canny edges on `YCbCr` images, you can use [`edgecolor.m`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8267-edge-detection-of-color-images).

Comment: This also returns 0 for all images. :(

Comment: Weird, it returns a big number on my testing. What image did you test on?

Comment: I will attach it with my question. Can you also show your code you tested? I tested it on 2-3 images.

Comment: @OptimusPrime I just test your image, return `10130`.

Comment: Yes, i don't know how, it is returning the same answer as nnz(). Thanks a lot for your help. Now I am not sure whose answer to accept.

Comment: @OptimusPrime It doesn't matter which one to accept as long as they helped you. Up-voting is already a type of accepting. :P

Comment: Yes I accept Divakar's as it had answers to both the parts and the method for the first was better. But, thanks a ton to you too. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is also efficient way to count the num of edge pixels.

```
count =length(find(BW(:)==1));
```